# I want to display a translucent background exposed as a component throughout the view in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Nuxt Version: 2.11.0

Hello.

I created a Loading Component that displays a translucent background and loading animation when loading.

Just load this component on the page, so the background image doesn't cover the header and footer areas, only the page area.

To solve this problem in the layout file, I created a device in the layout to control the loading components.

However, this issue was not addressed because the `v-bind: prop = ""` cannot be used in the `<nuxt />` tag.

In conclusion, I want to display the translucent background of the loading component throughout the view.

How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

First, we set the following configuration in `nuxt.config.js`.

```
export default {
    loading: '~/components/Loading.vue',
}
```

`Loading.vue` is equivalent to the code in the `Using a Custom Loading Component` section of the following link.

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading/#using-a-custom-loading-component

Next, I wrote two kinds of code in `pages/Page.vue`.

```
export default {
    mounted() {
        // this.$nextTick: Wait for the DOM to be updated.
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.$nuxt.$loading.start()

            setTimeout(() => this.$nuxt.$loading.finish(), 3000)
        })
    },
    methods: {
        // It is executed when the button which calls this function is pressed.
        whenClicked() {
            this.$nuxt.$loading.start()

            // Code...

            this.$nuxt.$loading.finish()
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code above, I can see that Loading looks the way I want it.

`this.$nextTick` referenced the following link:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html?#vm-nextTick

I posted a weird question because I rarely used vue.js and nuxt.js.

I'm sorry.

---

### More information

When 'this.$nuxt.$loading.start()' is executed, you should give a slight delay to the next line so that the loading component is displayed correctly before starting Logic.

### Example)

#### plugins/delay.js

```
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.prototype.$delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
```

#### nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
    plugins: [ '~/plugins/v-scroll-lock', '~/plugins/delay' ]
}
```

#### pages/Page.vue

```
async whenClicked() {
    this.$nuxt.$loading.start()

    await this.$delay(50)

    // Code...

    this.$nuxt.$loading.finish()
}
```